# Jenkins pipeline - How can I set parameters without removing all properties

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have pipeline script which configure params to job like:

```
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'develop'),
  ])
])
```

and this code override all job settings like config for EnvInject Plugin.

```
<properties>
...
- <EnvInjectJobProperty plugin="envinject@2.1">
-   <info>
-     <propertiesContent>ENVVAR=varvalue</propertiesContent>
-     <secureGroovyScript plugin="script-security@1.25">
-       <script></script>
-       <sandbox>true</sandbox>
-     </secureGroovyScript>
-     <loadFilesFromMaster>false</loadFilesFromMaster>
-   </info>
-   <on>true</on>
-   <keepJenkinsSystemVariables>true</keepJenkinsSystemVariables>
-   <keepBuildVariables>true</keepBuildVariables>
-   <overrideBuildParameters>false</overrideBuildParameters>
- </EnvInjectJobProperty>
...
</properties>
```

I want to keep these settings or set them back in properties block.

Have anyone an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out 
just add [$class: ...] after parameters block

```
properties(
  [
    parameters([
      string(name: 'BRANCH', defaultValue: 'develop'),
    ])
  ],
  [
    $class: 'EnvInjectJobProperty',
    info: [
      loadFilesFromMaster: false,
      propertiesContent: "ENVVAR=envvalue",
      secureGroovyScript: [
        classpath: [],
        sandbox: true,
        script: ''
      ]
    ],
    keepBuildVariables: true,
    keepJenkinsSystemVariables: true,
    on: true
  ]
)
```